# MySQL to calculate SUM with foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `1.material_line_item` and `2.item_master` there is a foreign key relation between two tables (`item_master_id` present in `material_line_item`) and there is a column called `item_code` in `item_master`. So I want a Join Query to display the `item_code` with my current query.

[image: **item_master_table**]

[image: **material_line_item_table**]

Comment: Foreign keys are there for data consistency purpose. (Make no difference when SELECT.)

Comment: so any solution for this?

Comment: Can you add sample table data as text, and also the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by joining the `item_master` table to a subquery of `material_line_item` which calculates the aggregates you want for each item master id value.  I am selecting all columns available though you are free to choose whichever columns you want.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM item_master t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item_master_id,
           SUM(received_quantity) AS Total_Received_Qty,
           SUM(ordered_quantity)  AS Total_Ordered_Qty
    FROM material_line_item
    GROUP BY item_master_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.item_master_id
```

Comment: Great :) @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

you can simply join the two tables like

```
select item.item_master_id, master.item_id, Sum(received_quantity), 
sum(ordered_quantity) from material_line_item item
left join item_master master on item.item_master_id = master.id
group by item.item_master_id, master.item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select a.item_master_id,a.Total_received_qty,a.Total_ordered_Qty,b.item_code from (select      item_master_id,
        sum(received_quantity) Total_received_qty,
        sum(ordered_quantity) Total_ordered_Qty
       from material_line_item
       group by item_master_id) a, item_master b where a.item_master_id =b.item_master_id
```

Hope it will help.